# How to eliminate arbitrary constant in differential equation using Python

Tags: python

I'm just wondering if python can solve elimination of arbitrary constant in differential equation.

For example we have a function

```
y = ax and bxe^(2x)
```

We can use the 1st and 2nd derivative to have two equation. By having two equation we can now eliminate two constant variable a and b. I just don't know how to put the code. Can someone know how to do this?

Comment: Sympy can be used to write algebraic statements and take derivatives: https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: can you please make a code for that?